# Keep wifi on during Android Zero-touch enrollment

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, device-policy-manager, wso2-iot

I created a json by following guide here https://developers.google.com/zero-touch/guides/customer/emm#provision

My sample json:

```
{
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "sample-component-name",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "device admin signature",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "http://download/location/that.apk",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION": false, 
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE": {
    "serverurl": "my-mdm.server.url", 
    "gid": "testGid", 
    "un":"testUn",
    "pw":"testPass"
},
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID": "wifi-ssid",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD": "correct-password",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PROXY_HOST": "my-wifi.proxy.host.url",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PROXY_PORT": 9999
}
```

Now the problem is when device connects to wifi, it takes few minutes to actually download apk and install. During that time, sometimes screen turns off which causes wifi to sleep. I understand this it to save battery, but it is sort failing the zero-touch idea.

I found link to a list of Global Settings on DevicePolicyManager doc page. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY
However I am not sure how to set this property through enrollment json. Can anybody please share any doc or example on how to achieve this?

I tried to add `wifi_sleep_policy = 2` in EXTRAS_BUNDLE, but it didn't work :(

Device is on Android-7-Nougat.